# Change Fragment layout on orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need a solution! error in addView() i don´t know the answer.....

I want to change the layout, using the previous views

i need help!

chart ---- https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Process: com.example.tiago.alsrm_android, PID: 23337
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3784)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3637)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3582)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3558)
                                                                                     at com.example.tiago.alsrm_android.Fragment.EDA_Fragment.onConfigurationChanged(EDA_Fragment.java:174)

public class EDA_Fragment extends Fragment {

```
private Intent intentService;
private Chart chart = null;
private View fragmentRootContainer;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(fragmentRootContainer == null) {
        fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, container, false);

        if (chart == null)
            chart = new Chart((LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart), EDA, 1023f, 1f);


    return fragmentRootContainer;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
    viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, null);

        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());


    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, null);

        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is chart  and ChartLine?

Comment: also add logcat......

Comment: loagcat add.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

------first--------

add this in AndroidManifest

```
android:name=".Activity.EDA_Activity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

------second----------

```
  in layout PORTRAIT add this -> android:orientation="vertical"

  in layout LANDSCAPE add this ->  android:orientation="horizontal"
```

--------third-----------

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView();
    if(linearLayout != null)
        linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup)chart.getChart().getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null)
            parentViewGroup.removeView(chart.getChart());

        fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, true);
        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup)chart.getChart().getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null)
            parentViewGroup.removeView(chart.getChart());

        fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, true);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, false);

        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());
    }
}
```